# Nginx rewrite to remove folder name

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I would like to remove the app name from a maganolia CMS installation on tomcat running on port 8080 in folder /magnoliaAuthor so I tried:

```
location / {

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/magnoliaAuthor/ ;
    }
```

The root page (/) opens but I discoverd that no pictures or css is loading because assets inside the page are linked as:

```
/magnoliaAuthor/.resources/defaultMagnoliaLoginForm/login.css
```

So they are sent to tomcat as

```
/magnoliaAuthor/magnoliaAuthor/.resources/defaultMagnoliaLoginForm/login.css
```

and result in 404

I tried tens of combinations of rewrite rules, splitting as two locations but nothing works, either I get the home page if I try  to access a CSS or the app name is stripped completely even from the proxy destination or I get into infinite redirection loops.

my current trial is:

```
location / {

        rewrite ^(.*) /magnoliaAuthor/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
```

basically i wish to rewrite:

```
/ -> /magnoliaAuthor/
/magnoliaAuthor/* -> /magnoliaAuthor/*
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/$ /magnoliaAuthor/ break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution would probably be to deploy `/magnoliaAuthor` at the root of the Tomcat servlet container.

Otherwise you can use either a *rewrite*:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/magnoliaAuthor/(.*)$ /$1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/magnoliaAuthor/;
}
```

or two locations:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/magnoliaAuthor/;
}
location /magnoliaAuthor/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

If you proceed this way, however, you'll still end up sometimes with a `/magnoliaAuthor` in the browser address bar, which probably you want to avoid.